# Gnuradio possible path issue prevents use python programs

Tags: python-3.x, linux, path, syntax-error, gnuradio

I'm having some issues using gnuradio with python programs. I am trying to use gnuradio with gr-satellites' python programs to decode packets from CubeSats. When I try to run the command `python filename.py`, I receive the following output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "taurus1_telemetry_parser.py", line 23, in <module>
    from gnuradio import gr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .runtime_swig import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/runtime_swig.py", line 117
    def value(self) -> "PyObject *":
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(BELOW COMMENTS EDITED FROM ORIGINAL POST)

It turns out that my system was set up to run python 2.7.15, when gnuradio runs python3. I adjusted my system so that it ran off of python 3.6.8, based on the instructions posted [here.](https://github.com/daniestevez/gr-satellites/wiki/Installation-of-GNUradio-3.8-under-Ubuntu-18.04-LTS,-(K)Ubuntu-19.04,-Mint-19.2-Mate,-Mint-19.2-Cinnamon-or-Ubuntu-19.10) This changed my system to run python3.6.8 correctly, but I think I have installed gnuradio incorrectly, as I am still getting errors.

Now, if I run the command `python3 filename.py` I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "taurus1_telemetry_parser.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import by701_telemetry
ImportError: cannot import name 'by701_telemetry'
```

I successfully uninstalled the pybombs version of gnuradio using the command `pybombs remove gnuradio uhd`, as was suggested in the comments below, leaving only the ppa version installed.

Since there were so many issues with the gnuradio config, I tried to see if I could easily uninstall the ppa version and just start fresh with gnuradio. I went into my directory for gnuradio (Desktop/gnuradio/build) and tried a `make uninstall`. Doing a `make uninstall` process did not produce any errors, but this did not seem to remove gnuradio from my system entirely.

gnuradio can still be found in `/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages`, and I still get the ImportError when I try to run a python script. However, now when I enter `head /usr/local/bin/gnuradio-companion`, I get the following message:

```
head: cannot open '/usr/local/bin/gnuradio-companion' for reading: No such file or directory
```

The output of `which gnuradio-companion` is:

```
 /usr/bin/gnuradio-companion
```

I'm kind of lost on what to do here now. Any ideas on how gnuradio can either be fixed or uninstalled entirely?

Answer (score 1):

The problem most probably is that you are starting your program with python2 while gnuradio has been compiled with python3.

You need to specify explicitly that a python3 interpreter needs to be used on the first line of your program (this line is called [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)))

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

or start your program the following way

```
$ python3 ./my_program.py
```

> I installed gnuradio through ppa, as well as pybombs.

Having two versions could cause a lot of problems. My recommendation is to use the PPA version and remove the one installed with pybombs

```
$ pybombs remove gnuradio uhd
```

Comment: Hi, Vasil - I implemented what you suggested, but I am getting a few new errors now. I adjusted my original post to detail these. Do you have any thoughts on the new issues?

Comment: "could cause a lot of problems": Will **definitely** cause a lot of problem. I do not recommend the usage of PyBOMBS for 99.5% of users. Great answer!

Comment: @sroger13 probably some remnants of manual installations mixing with the PPA installation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller do you have any thoughts on how I might want to get rid of the manual installations? Are there specific folders that I might want to manually delete or something similar?

Comment: @sroger13 Execute `find /usr/local/ -name "*gnuradio*" -or -name "*uhd*" -or -name "*volk*" -or -name "*pmt*"`, check if the output contains only gnuradio related files and return the same command with `-delete` option in order to delete all of the listed files.